# Android 2D framework for Graph Visualisation

Tags: android, graphics, frameworks, 2d, visualization

I'm going to work in the next weeks on a visualisation project on android tablets and mobile devices. This is a kind of project where there is webservices calls, databases and little processing but a lot of data visualisation and manipulation. Mainly 2D (advanced charts and advanced graphs). Like http://max-planck-research-networks.net/.

And I was wondering if there was some framework on android that could accelerate my devs. I heard about game engine (like AndEnine and cocos) but i'm looking for something more like processing.org. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a graphing library like http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/ or http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently looking for a framwork that could do this. Up to now the best I could find was JUNG (http://jung.sourceforge.net/). JUNG uses swing in its renderer, so to use it with android a new renderer would need to be built.